# Can flagging comments be disabled on a specific SE site?

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

On *English Language and Usage* I flagged a comment, but it doesn't appear in the list of the flagged posts (I have access to the moderation tools, until the site is in beta phase). Does that mean flagging is disabled, on that site? Is it possible to disable it for a specific site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of flagged *comments* is only available to diamond moderators; the 10k tools (or in this case 2k tools) only give access to flagged *posts*. This is identical on all sites.

Comment: @baplha: Thank you for your reply.